# qTranslate-x How to get LSB for content submission form at frontend

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate, qtranslate-x

I have a plugin and theme installed on my WP. Through instructions and comparisons with working examples I managed to put together a working i18n-config.json that makes the LSB appear and work for the plugin options and input on the admin page.

The front-end will have various parts where users will put in their info. One example of a page like that is:
https://wedme.gr/en/submit-listing/

I have tried various approaches to get the LSB to appear on this page so users can input their data in both languages but I just can't make it happen. I tried doing this both through a theme i18n-config.json and a plugin i18n-config.json and both at the same time but it seems I am doing something wrong. I won't bore you with the variations I tried because it was a lot (and I'm guessing most of it will probably make you laugh).

Is my approach all wrong? Is this one of those cases where it is not as simple as adding a i18n-config.json?

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Comment: Please show your code. Otherwise, how can we tell if your approach "is all wrong"?

Comment: Apologies. When I say my approach I mean whether or not this is doable through a simple JSON code or if this needs something more complex. So, what do you think?

Comment: Your post seem similar to Hervigg at qTranslate-XT's issue. But he reported at github that wedme.gr had LSB implemented in the right way. But when commenting at SO, one should not say, "most of it will probably make you laugh", because we all learn at some point.